# Psql query to convert array of json into rows

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, rows

I have an array of json -

```
[{id:1,quantity:100},{id:2,quantity:25},{id:3,quantity:68}]
```

How do convert this into following using query in postgres -

```
Id     |Quantity
-----------------
1      |100
2      |25
3      |68
```

If it is at all possible, I want to know how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`jsonb_array_elements()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)

```
select t ->> 'id' as id, t ->> 'quantity' as quantity
from jsonb_array_elements('[{"id":1,"quantity":100},{"id":2,"quantity":25},{"id":3,"quantity":68}]') as t
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/YBUER58387